# Python: Deleting files reverse-alphabetically if a certain number of files in in a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well, deleting files with a smaller date (though I believe numbers work the same as letters). For example, we have the following files in one directory named "BOB":

```
10-10-2000.txt
11-10-2000.txt
12-10-2000.txt
13-10-2000.txt
14-10-2000.txt
```

But I only want 4, so I need to remove the least-recent date which is the 10-10-2000.txt. However, this can't be done just by removing the least-recently created file as the 10-10-2000.txt may have been made just yesterday.

Thanks.

Comment: `time.strptime()` might help

Comment: You should read the help file for this site. It will tell you that you need to show us the code you've written in an attempt to solve the problem for yourself. To write your code I suggest you read the Python help files for pathlib which may provide most of the functionality you need.

Comment: @user2399871 where is your [mcve], please?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create datetime objects from the file names, and then do comparisons on them. I won't write out your code for you, but something of the like:

```
import datetime as dt
file_names = ... # (maybe try os.listdir()?)
dates = []
for name in file_names:
    dates.append((name, dt.datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%m-%Y.txt")))
# ... logic to sort dates ...
os.remove(dates[0][0]) # if the sort worked, and your first result is the first date
```

If you want help with sorting the dates, ask me, but you should be able to use basic comparison operators once you have dates